# Twitter rate limit exceeded with heroku scheduler, need help to resolve this issue

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, tweepy

I am working on a Twitter bot using Tweepy and hosting it on Heroku. My script is supposed to post images to Twitter at scheduled intervals. However, I am encountering a problem where each time the script runs, the "sleeping for time" duration (due to rate limiting) increases, even though I have not hit the rate limit according to Twitter's documentation.

The log shows "Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for X seconds," and X keeps increasing with each execution. I even turned off my worker to prevent any potential over-usage but the issue persists.

Here's a snippet of the log:

Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 316 seconds.
Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 901 seconds.

I have set wait_on_rate_limit=True in my Tweepy API and Client configurations, yet the problem continues. I am using tweepy.Client.create_tweet to post tweets.

I have checked the rate limit status and I am nowhere near exceeding the limits. The increasing sleep time is confusing and hindering the bot's functionality. Any insights on why this might be happening and how to resolve it would be appreciated.

I dont know how to move on forward but this is the python script i am using :

```
import tweepy
import random
import os

# Enter API tokens below
bearer_token = 'xxx'
consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'

# V1 Twitter API Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# V2 Twitter API Authentication
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token,
    consumer_key,
    consumer_secret,
    access_token,
    access_token_secret,
    wait_on_rate_limit=True,
)

def random_file_path(folder):
    return os.path.join(folder, random.choice(os.listdir(folder)))

def random_message():
    messages = [
        "Here's a new wallpaper for you!  #Wallpaper",
        "Brighten up your screen with this! ✨ #Wallpaper",
        "Looking for a change? Try this wallpaper.  #Wallpaper",
        "Add some flair to your device with this wallpaper!  #Wallpaper",
        "A fresh look for your screen. Enjoy!  #Wallpaper",
        "Transform your device with this wallpaper.  #Wallpaper",
        "Elevate your screen aesthetics with this one.  #Wallpaper",
        "Because your device deserves the best!  #Wallpaper",
        "A wallpaper says a lot about you. Here's a suggestion.  #Wallpaper",
        "Dress your screen with our pick!  #Wallpaper",
        "Wallpapers speak louder than words. Check this choice.  #Wallpaper",
        "Bored of your current look? We've got you covered.  #Wallpaper",
        "Daily dose of art for your device!  #Wallpaper",
        "Why settle? Change your view with this wallpaper.  #Wallpaper",
        "Experience a fresh perspective with this background.  #Wallpaper",
        "Let your screen reflect your mood. Try this out!  #Wallpaper",
        "Wallpaper upgrade alert! Check this out. ⬆️ #Wallpaper",
        "Beauty is in the details. Enjoy this detailed artwork for your screen.  #Wallpaper",
        "Why be mundane when you can stand out? New wallpaper alert!  #Wallpaper"
    ]
    return random.choice(messages)

# Upload image to Twitter. Randomly selects image from mobilephotos folder.
media_id = api.media_upload(filename=random_file_path("mobilephotos")).media_id_string

# Text to be Tweeted. Randomly selects a message.
text = random_message()

# Send Tweet with Text and media ID
client.create_tweet(text=text, media_ids=[media_id])
print("Tweeted!")
```